# Issue with C2DM registration-id when the user uninstalls the application

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, apple-push-notifications, android-c2dm

When the user uninstalls the app from his android device, it means that the registration_id for C2DM is no more valid. Now, how does the server which sends the push notifications know this. With Apple, there is something called Apple-feedback which lists out all the device-tokens (Android folks, read as registration-id) that are invalid.

Please, help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for a sollution to this, so far I've only found one useful sollution which is mentioned here: http://groups.google.com/group/android-c2dm/browse_thread/thread/8e58ed95a0818716

In short: When you SEND the message to the device, send an UID with it (eg. generated on first install). When a message is received in the application, check if the UID is the same, if it is, do you thing (eg create notification), otherwise ignore it, and send a msg to your C2DM server that this Google C2DM registration ID is not valid anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the reason C2DM are refreshing the Registration ID after random time. If user uninstall the App from his device, he is not not going to update his/her Registration ID either. Then he will not getting any Push Notifications anymore.